# MS-Access-2016 Query Language 'ORDER BY' Clause

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

A simple query using ORDER BY.. but giving Syntax error in ORDER BY clause. (Error 3138). Not finding any problem.

I have tried the following code:

```
SELECT [Veh in Netwk (fzp)].[Sim Sec(s)], [Veh in Netwk (fzp)].[Veh No], [Veh in Netwk (fzp)].[Link No], [Veh in Netwk (fzp)].[Lane No], [Veh in Netwk (fzp)].[Posn (m)]
FROM [Veh in Netwk (fzp)]
ORDER BY [Veh in Netwk (fzp)].[Sim Sec(s)] ASC
OFFSET 10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 15 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access SQL you have **SELECT TOP n**. So use a subquery and this skeleton:

```
Select Top 15 * From YourTable
Where ID Not In 
    (Select Top 10 ID From YourTable Order By ID Desc)
Order By ID Desc
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav for your kind assistance.

Answer (score 0):

[MS Access SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/microsoft-access-sql-reference) does not support `OFFSET` or `FETCH NEXT`.